# Sorting an array with pre-sorted partitions

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have an array that is already sorted in partitions of 4:

```
2, 23, 45, 55, 1, 4, 23, 74545, 75, 234, 323, 9090, 2, 43, 6342, 323452
```

What would be the most efficient way to sort this array?  Note: the array size is always even and the program knows that every 4 elements are sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to use [strand sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strand_sort) for this.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) for problems like this.